# A result was returned when none was expected error in exposed ORM with KTOR

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

This is the code block of DAO layer with kotlin and Ktor with exposed ORM

```
query = "WITH temporaryTable (averageValue) as (SELECT avg(Attr1) ....;"
transaction{
    exec(query){
        while(it.next()){
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

After running the code I am getting `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected` error.

***SELECT*** query is working in this way but ***WITH*** query is giving the above error.

Comment: Perhaps the thing is trying to guess from the SQL statement if it will return a result or not, and is not hip to CTEs. This will also be interesting when used with `EXPLAIN`. Or perhaps even with `DELETE ... RETURNING`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to provide `explicitStatementType` param to help Exposed to understand that your query is a select:

```kotlin
val query = "WITH temporaryTable (averageValue) as (SELECT avg(Attr1) ....;"
transaction{
    exec(query, explicitStatementType = StatementType.SELECT){
        while(it.next()){
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```